# i'm getting error whenEver i try to get data from my db using this function(i'm using kotlin with android studio)

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

```
fun readChore(id:Int):Chore{
     val db:SQLiteDatabase=writableDatabase

    val cursor:Cursor=db.query(TABLE_NAME,arrayOf(KEY_ID,KEY_CHORE_ASSIGNED_TO, KEY_CHORE_ASSIGNED_BY,
               KEY_CHORE_ASSINED_TIME),KEY_ID+"=?",arrayOf(id.toString()),
               null,null,null,null)

    Log.d("position",cursor.position.toString())

    cursor.moveToFirst()

    val chore=Chore(
            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_CHORE_NAME)),
            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_CHORE_ASSIGNED_TO)),
            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_CHORE_ASSIGNED_BY)),
            cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_CHORE_ASSINED_TIME))
    )

    return chore
}
```

But all i'm getting is an error__saying ...**"Failed to read row 0, column -1 from a CursorWindow which has 1 rows, 4 columns."**

Comment: You are trying to access the -1th element in columns, see if the column name is right or the index (if being used) is correct You might not also have column with that exact name, perhaps misspelled or wrong case etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add `KEY_CHORE_NAME` to the selected rows

```
val cursor:Cursor=db.query(TABLE_NAME,arrayOf(KEY_ID, KEY_CHORE_NAME ,KEY_CHORE_ASSIGNED_TO, KEY_CHORE_ASSIGNED_BY,
           KEY_CHORE_ASSINED_TIME),KEY_ID+"=?",arrayOf(id.toString()),
           null,null,null,null)
```

For future debugging you can use `Databaseutils.dumpCursor()` to see the contents of your cursor, which is otherwise hard to see.

Also don't forget to close the cursor `cursor.close()` before the return statement.

Comment: Bugs like this happen to all of us, no worries. If you are unsure what the database returns you can check with DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor()